# Route from server to other computer

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, home-networking

I have server based on Debian with Apache 2.x installed. On router, all incoming connections on selected ports are forwarded to this server. Also, I have my own working computer with server.

I want access to my home computer (192.168.1.101) by server (192.168.1.100) with URL like `http://my-ip.com/my-home-computer/`.

That kind of routing is possible?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use reverse proxies.  Apache supports them.

Reverse proxies are where a web server, such as Apache, will take requests going to a certain URL, and forward it to another webserver.  It will then forward back the replies.

This works easiest when your "backend" webserver's URL is the same prefix as the front end, i.e. you want to reach `http://192.168.1.101/my-home-computer` from `http://192.168.1.100/my-home-computer`.

You can set up mapping to different URL's, such as reaching just `http://192.168.1.101/` from `http://192.168.1.100/my-home-computer`, but some web applications can be problematic, and then you'll have to get into on-the-fly rewriting of HTTP content, which can sometimes be difficult when Javascript is involved.

Plenty of info online on how to configure it exactly - [here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) is a good starting point.